# I'm creating a unique id out of two ids. what's the best way to code a sql safety net for null values when concatenated?

Tags: sql, null

I'm creating a  unique id out of two ids: if I create an id like this
(tid::text || '_' || id::text) as master_id
what's the best way to prevent null values in tid or id from creating a null value for the master_id?

Comment: which dbms are you using?

Comment: I would suggest, don't. This is looking like a smelly solution. And also your question seems an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). So explain what exactly is your problem so we can better help.

Answer (score 0):

If this is meant to generate some sort of unique id, a solution to this will likely cause problems in uniqueness.

That being said, there are many ways to solve this depending on control of the data store:

If you have control of table definition and both fields are in the same table, then "not null" constraints on each field during table definition will prevent a possibility of nulls for both fields.
If your query is using left joins from 2 different tables to retrieve the fields, the possibility of nulls still exist.

If you have no control of table definition and/or are using left joins in your query to access both fields from different tables, then using the ISNULL SQL function on both fields should eliminate the possibility of nulls on both fields.